# Can I write grpc with C++ server and nodejs client?

Tags: c++, node.js, grpc

**gRPC with C++ server and nodejs client**

I learning gRPC and wonder that we can write code for c++ server and nodejs client

Comment: Yes. That's part of the basic idea--write a language-neutral specification, and it can generate clients and servers in any supported language that can talk with each other.

Comment: Thanks @JerryCoffin, I was stucked when write client nodejs, have you have example or another thing for help?

Comment: Sorry, but no--I leave node.js to other people. For that matter, I haven't used gRPC in quite a while. Most of my recent work along this general line has been using Google flat buffers instead.

Comment: Can you share some tips for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The main idea behind gRPC is the language independent protocol. There are several supported languages. On the [website](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/) they show "hello world" examples for each language as well as more in depth tutorials. Try to go from there.